# Using POST for .NET ApiController action with name starting with "Delete"

Tags: asp.net-apicontroller

I'd like to have an `ApiController` with a controller action that accepts POST requests and has a name that starts with `Delete`. I'm using the following jQuery:

```
function DeleteMyDomainObjectButton_OnClick() {
    var $div = $(this).closest("div.domain-object");
    var url = baseUrl + "Api/MyBusiness/DeleteMyDomainObject";
    var dto = {
        "MyDomainObjectId": $div.find("input[name=MyDomainObjectId]").val()
    };

    $.ajax({
        complete: DeleteMyDomainObjectAjax_OnComplete
      , dataType: "json"
      , contentType: "application/json"
      , accept: "applcation/json"
      , data: JSON.stringify(dto)
      , error: DeleteMyDomainObjectAjax_OnError
      , method: "POST"
      , success: DeleteMyDomainObjectAjax_OnSuccess
      , url: url
    });
}
```

I keep getting a 405: `{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'POST'."}`. The response headers are:

```
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Allow: DELETE
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 07 Jul 2015 20:45:35 GMT
Content-Length: 73
```

I did check the request headers, and it actually is sending a POST. Here's my controller:

```
public class BaseApiController : ApiController
{
    /* Properties for All API Controllers set by DI */
}

public class MyBusinessController : BaseApiController
{
    public virtual MyDomainObject FooBar(DeleteMyDomainObjectDto dto)
    {
        return this.DeleteMyDomainObject(p_input);
    }

    [HttpPost] // Doesn't work.
    // [AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)] // Also doesn't work.
    public virtual MyDomainObject DeleteMyDomainObject(DeleteMyDomainObjectDto dto)
    {
        return BusinessLogic.DeleteMyDomainObject(dto)
    }
}
```

Now, if I change the controller action that I reference from jQuery to `FooBar`, it works.

Question: How can I turn off the magic sauce that makes the `ApiController` only allow DELETE requests for controller actions with names starting with the string `Delete`? Or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: `HttpPost` and `[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]` are synonyms. Does it already work if you remove one of them?

Comment: No. Leaving just one makes no difference. I put both in the question to indicate that I tried both; I'll edit the question.